# Projection valued measure on $(\lambda-\epsilon, \lambda+\epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a bounded self adjoint operator, Show that $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$ iff $P_{\lambda-\epsilon, \lambda+\epsilon}(A)\neq \{0\}$ given $\epsilon>0$. How would you prove this fact? Any hints/ideas?

$P_{E}$ denote the projection valued measure on $E$.

Comment: Suppose $P_{\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon}=0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $R(\lambda)=\int \frac{1}{\mu-\lambda}dP(\mu)$. Show that $R(\lambda)$ is bounded and $(A-\lambda I)R(\lambda)=I=R(\lambda)(A-\lambda I)$.